# How to select rows with no missing data in python?

Tags: python, pandas, na

I can only find questions on here that are for selecting rows with missing data using pandas in python.

How can I select rows that are complete and have no missing values?

I am trying to use:
`data.notnull()` which gives me true or false values per row but I don't know how to do the actual selection of only rows where all values are true for not being NA. Also unsure if `notnull()` is just considering rows with zeros as false whereas I would accept a zero in a row as a value, I am just looking to find rows with no NAs.

Comment: `filtered_data=data.dropna()`? or `data.dropna(inplace='True')`?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your data, if it's in a dataframe df, and you want to drop rows with any missing values, try

```
newdf = df.dropna(how = 'any')
```

This is what pandas does by default, so should actually be the same as

```
newdf = df.dropna()
```